# A secure PHP class connecting to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone recommend some simple and secure PHP/MySQL Database class for the database interaction?

Comment: What doesn't [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) do that you want the class to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just use the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) class :)

Answer (score 1):

Here at work we use PDO for that kind of things. Clear enough imho

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out MDB2....

http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2

Answer (score 0):

All extensions (mysql, mysqli, pdo_mysql) are safe, if you use them correctly!

We use PDO, though, which appears to be the easiest one: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
Just remember to use prepared statements (which are "100% safe" against SQL Injections, when used correctly). If you can't use them, at least use methods like PDO::quote().

Comment: If used correctly, `$res = exec('echo \'select * from ...\'|mysql -u -pblahblah dbname');` would be safe as well. Preferable? heck no...

Comment: Prepared statements are not "100% safe" against injections.  It's hard to say what "used correctly" means.  Basically, you have to be careful no matter what you are doing, prepared statements or no.